# Samsung galaxy a10 overheating

Tags: samsung, android-10, android-versions

My Samsung galaxy a10 keeps giving overheating notification but phone is almost cold.
Any solution?

Comment: May be it is a wrong translation and should be a "temperature warning" (because of a temperature **too low** or **too high**)?